# CSS zoom in on image hover

Tags: html, css, hover, zooming

Using the following code I can zoom in on the image on hover:

```css
.image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url(http://duncanlock.net/images/posts/better-figures-images-plugin-for-pelican/dummy-200x200.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image:hover {
  background-size: 120% 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

How can I do this using an `<img>` tag instead of a `<div>` with a background image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Zoom an Image on Mouse Hover using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491728/how-to-zoom-an-image-on-mouse-hover-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the image in a div:

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
</div>
```

And apply this CSS:

```
.item { //This is the container div
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.item img { //This is the img
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item:hover img { //This is the img during hover
  transform: scale(1.5); //Increase or decrease this number to change the zoom
}
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.item img {  
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it is not what I want exactly. In my example code you can see that it zoomed in, but the dimensions of image stays the same, so it means that it didn't cross border. Is it possible? Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes. So for example I have an article on my website. Article have title, image and description. Image width will be 100% relative to the width of article, but height will be set to "auto". When someone hover on this image, it will zoom image center in, but image shouldn't increase  his width and height, or the part which cross the border shoud be hidden.

Comment: @Genjik How's my answer?

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I still have one question, if I will wrap image in div, and I set to this div height: auto it will disappear. I need it  because image can have for example  height: 150px or height: 250px; It will depend on the width(for responsive).

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to zoom on hover with an image inserted with `<img>`, you need to use transform and transition to have a smooth zoom.

```css
#imageZoom{
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: all 1s;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

#imageZoom img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="imageZoom">
  <img src="http://duncanlock.net/images/posts/better-figures-images-plugin-for-pelican/dummy-200x200.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried it before, but it is not the desicion because when I use tranform: scale() property it will increase the width and height of an image, but I dont want to do so. Please see my example of code to understand what I mean and want.

Comment: Amended with snippet

Comment: Funny we suggested same solution at the same time ;-)