# How to Zoom an Image on Mouse Hover using CSS?

Tags: css

I just want to zoom the image. I need to give the height of my product list automatically because it is not responsive, but when I do that the container stretches down, how can I avoid this?

```css
.zoom-img {
  width: 300px;
  height:auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom-img  img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.zoom-img img:hover   {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-img">
  <img src="https://www.arthenos.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Manzara_fotografciligi_2-1200x900.jpg" alt="This zooms-in really well and smooth">
</div>
```

My hover image
[image]

Comment: can you post a complete example? your code works

Comment: i shared now...

Comment: Try adding the hover effect to the `div` instead of the image

Answer (score 6):

Use `object-fit` property.
I made all images have 1:1 aspect ratio.

```css
.zoom-img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.zoom-img img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-img">
  <img src="https://www.arthenos.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Manzara_fotografciligi_2-1200x900.jpg" alt="This zooms-in really well and smooth">
</div>
```

Or use `aspect-ratio` property too.

```css
.zoom-img {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom-img img {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.zoom-img img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-img">
  <img src="https://www.arthenos.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Manzara_fotografciligi_2-1200x900.jpg" alt="This zooms-in really well and smooth">
</div>
```

Comment: You can use those for many images that have different aspect ratios.

Comment: I did what you said but the result is still the same :\

Comment: @Ferhat, can you tell me your device and os if you are using pc?

Comment: ofc, windows 10

Comment: Windows10 Edge, right?

Answer (score 0):

#### Now there is a `scale` property which let's you zoom without any further lines needed.

Just use this on hover:

```
scale: 1.2;
```

---

But **height: auto** would still be a problem. The height needs to be fixed either way or it will always overflow, use **either a fixed height or** make it fixed from the width via **aspect-ratio: x / y**

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use overflow: clip; instead of overflow: hidden;

```
.zoom-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: clip;
}

.zoom-img img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.zoom-img img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

<div class="zoom-img">
  <img src="https://www.arthenos.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Manzara_fotografciligi_2-1200x900.jpg" alt="This zooms-in really well and smooth">
</div>
```